# Making an Atom package in JS: go to line

Tags: javascript, atom-editor

I'm making an Atom package in JavaScript.
How do I jump to a particular line, similar to what you can do with Ctrl-G. Is there a function like goToLine(line) that I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

atom has a pre-installed package called go-to-line and has a function [navigate](https://github.com/atom/go-to-line/blob/master/lib/go-to-line-view.js#L55). it's as simple as this:

```
import { Point } from 'atom';

const editor = atom.workspace.getActiveTextEditor();
const position = new Point(row, column);

editor.setCursorBufferPosition(position);
editor.scrollToBufferPosition(position, { center: true });
```

Comment: Is there a way to go to an absolute position, like 50 characters from the start?